# How do I filter a tuple of types depending on whether an expression is valid in Boost.Hana?

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming, boost-hana

In a reduced example I have two types with in a tuple and I want to create another tuple that only contains the types where an expression is valid (in this example I'm using the + operator).

My attempt is like so:

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/experimental/printable.hpp>

#include <iostream>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

struct foo {};

const auto result{hana::filter(hana::tuple_t<int, foo>, [](auto type) {
  const auto has_plus{hana::is_valid([](auto t)
    -> decltype((void) hana::traits::declval(t) + hana::traits::declval(t)) {})};

  return has_plus(type);
})};

int main()
{
  std::cout << hana::experimental::print(result) << std::endl;
}
```

This outputs '()', ie. no types matched where I would expect that the tuple `result` should contain `type<int>`.

I am using the Boost.Hana version that is packaged with Boost 1.62.

Comment: By the way, you can simplify your function to:

`hana::filter(hana::tuple_t<int, foo>, hana::is_valid([](auto t)
  -> decltype((void)(hana::traits::declval(t) + hana::traits::declval(t))) { }
));`

This transformation of `[](auto x) { return f(x); }` to just `f` is called [eta-reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B7-conversion).

Comment: @LouisDionne yeah that's more of a side effect from the reduced example that exhibited the issue i was having..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is with operator precedence.

```
(void)hana::traits::declval(t) + hana::traits::declval(t)
```

is the same as

```
((void)hana::traits::declval(t)) + hana::traits::declval(t)
```

The following yields the result you expected:

```
(void)(hana::traits::declval(t) + hana::traits::declval(t))
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/taSxLfcg7WVEhdEV)